# Sitecore integration With Logging Application Block

Tags: sitecore, logging-application-block

Is there a possibility to integrate Sitecore with Logging application block? I don't want to use the Log4Net logging rather Sitecore should use Logging application block write the log file.

Any pointer towards this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

I used next example to write to a database.
I have a database , and some stored procedure to write logs . 
inside the

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections>
```

you will have :

```
  <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c"/>
and after log4net section you will have : 


 <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
  <listeners>
  <add databaseInstanceName="yourDatabaseName" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog" addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c" name="DatabaseTraceListener"/>
  <add source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter" log="Application" machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c" name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener"/>
</listeners>
<formatters>
  <add template="{dictionary({value} |*****|&#xA;)}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e623e4d8c83fe71c" name="Text Formatter"/>
</formatters>
<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="DatabaseTraceListener"/>
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events"/>
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener"/>
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
```

I hope it will help you .